# Firebase database: invalid token in path

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, token

my question is this, I´m getting this error:
    `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Invalid token in path`, when I update a User´s node which from this code:

```
Map<String, Object> userUpdate = new HashMap<>();
        userUpdate.put("/" + Constants.Users + "/" + userEncEmail + "/profile_data/age", age);
        userUpdate.put("/" + Constants.Users + "/" + userEncEmail + "/profile_data/email", userEmail);
        userUpdate.put("/" + Constants.Users + "/" + userEncEmail + "/profile_data/gender", gender);
        userUpdate.put("/" + Constants.Users + "/" + userEncEmail + "/profile_data/name", userName);
        userUpdate.put("/" + Constants.Users + "/" + userEncEmail + "/profile_data/photo", "");
        userUpdate.put("/" + Constants.Users + "/" + userEncEmail + "/profile_data/video", "");

        userUpdate.put("/" + Constants.Users + "/" + userEncEmail + "/chat_data/osPlayerID", "");
        userUpdate.put("/" + Constants.Users + "/" + userEncEmail + "/chat_data/name", userName);
        userUpdate.put("/" + Constants.Users + "/" + userEncEmail + "/chat_data/photo", "");
        userUpdate.put("/" + Constants.Users + "/" + userEncEmail + "/chat_data/video", "");

        userUpdate.put("/" + Constants.Users + "/" + userEncEmail + "/status", false);//Set false by default

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().updateChildren(userUpdate).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
```

The rules from Firebase Database to this specific node are: true for write and read.

The Json expected is:

```
{
  $UserEMail: {
     chat_data: {
       name: "",
       osPlayerID: "",
       photo: "",
       video: ""
     },
     profile_data: {
      age: (int),
      email: "";
      gender: (int),
      name: "",
      photo: "",
      video: ""
    },
    status: (boolean)
  }
}
```

Comment: during testing the user is online always

Comment: Your hashMap() path seems wrong. Please share your database tree or expected JSON tree.

Comment: I´ve updated my question

Comment: Can you show the literal string of one full path that gives this error message? So one with the values of `userEncEmail` and `Constants.Users` filled in, instead of the variables.

Comment: Linking my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47328579/4625829)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that i was trying to insert an email like so `email@example.com` when Firebase doesn´t accept dots as part of a key of a node

Comment: yes, I was using a node name that contained a dot in it, I replace it using a comma

Comment: No need of preceding `"/"` before **Constants.Users** in the statement;                        `userUpdate.put("/" + Constants.Users + "/" + userEncEmail + "/chat_data/photo", "");`