# android firebase database Invalid token in path

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I did the base64 utf-8 encoding of the email.
Because it is a database key.
However, the following problems arise.
I need help.

**setValue at /user/aW1hZ2VfNTk1NkBuYXZlci5jb20=
failed: DatabaseError: Invalid token in path**

```
databaseReference.child("user").child(util.getBase64encode(email)).setValue(userModel)
```

help me...

Comment: log the base64 encrypted email and check if it's the same at your database

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/nemakev/edit?js,console which writes https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/44160089.json

Comment: The slash character, /, is not allowed in a Firebase token.  Many Base64 encodings use '/'.  Are you using a Base64 encoder that does not produce /.  For example, [uses this option](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#URL_SAFE).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the encoded string was having a new line at the end. Using `Base64.NO_WRAP` as mentioned by @Arvin in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081228/4625829) worked as a solution. My encoding function now looks like:

```
public static String encodeToBase64(String strToEncode) {
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        data = strToEncode.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

If you're aiming to be safe like what @BobSnyder mentioned in the comments above, you could still use `URL_SAFE` and just trim the String just to make sure.